# Flutter: performance issue in long lists with random colors

Tags: flutter, listview, listviewitem, flutter-listview

I have a List of items, each item has a color, when the list passes like 15 items the color of the items that are off-screen changes. I've tried with ListView.builder and ListView.custom and it's the same result.

Here's the code I use for the list:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return NoteItem(
              key: ValueKey(notes[index].id),
              note: notes[index],
              deleteNote: deleteNote,
            );
          },
          itemCount: notes.length,
          findChildIndexCallback: (Key key) {
            final ValueKey valueKey = key;
            final String data = valueKey.value;
            final index = notes.indexWhere((nt) => nt.id == data);
            return index >= 0 ? index : null;
          },
        ),
```

[Before Scrolling (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0V3D.png)

[After Scrolling (example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5leJ.png)

also, Is there any way to not have the same color as the last item added in the list?
I tried to add .toSet().toList() to my list of colors. but it still generate 2 of the same color in-a-row at some point.

Here's my colors list:

```
     Color _bgColor;

  @override
  void initState() {
    const availableColors = [
      Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 171, 168),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 122, 119),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 205, 155, 157),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 199, 201),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 167, 149),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 192, 181),
      Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 208, 228),
    ];

    _bgColor = availableColors[Random().nextInt(7)];

    super.initState();
  }
```

Can you help?

I'm new to flutter and I was trying to apply what I've learned so far so I'm sorry if the question is dumb :) also sorry for my bad English.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to pass the index to the NoteItem, like this for example

```
return NoteItem(
  key: ValueKey(notes[index].id)
  note: notes[index],
  deleteNote: deleteNote,
  index: index
);
```

and then change

```
_bgColor = availableColors[Random().nextInt(7)];
```

to

```
_bgColor = availableColors[widget.index % 7];
```

It won't be random anymore then, but at least consistent and no duplicate colors after each other

Comment: Thank you so much!! that helped a lot and it works pretty well.
I will try to make them random but this already gives a great result and put a big smile on my face! :) 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check that if present color is equal to previous color then choose color again.

If you can't implement, then tell me and I will help you.

Comment: Hi, Yes Thank you! I thought of that but didn't know how I could achieve it. Can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate random color.Simply pass the index also to your NoteItem class and set your index and your color will be chossed in order.

Color _bgColor;
static int index = 0;

@override

void initState() {

```
const availableColors = [

  Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 171, 168),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 122, 119),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 205, 155, 157),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 199, 201),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 167, 149),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 192, 181),
  Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 208, 228),
];

_bgColor = availableColors[index % 7];

super.initState();
```

}

Comment: Thank you! that really helped. it's now consistent and in order. Is there any way to make it random?